# Annihilator of c_0 in c

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and  $M\subset V$ 
Annihilator of $M$ is the set:

$$
M^{\perp} = \{f^* \in V^* : f^*(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in M \}
$$

Now let $V = c$ the space of sequences of real numbers, for which the limit exists and $M = c_0$ the space of sequences of real numbers, for which the limit equal $0$.

Why is $M^{\perp} = \{0\}$?

Comment: Do you know what is $c^*$?

Comment: @Feng yes, it’s $l_1$

Comment: This is clearly false. What about $f^*(x):=\lim x$?

Comment: @Justauser you are not right because every functional expressed as $f_y(x)= lim x + sum y_ix_i$

Comment: You should say that it is sequences of real numbers (I suppose so)

Comment: @JeanMarie thx, edited my question

Comment: @JeanMarie No, beacuse in my question $V = c$ and $M = c_0$, in the question above $V = M = c_0$

Comment: @kontsev_: $c^*=c_0^*$, so the distinction is irrelevant.

Comment: If $f^*\in M^\perp$ then $f^*(e_n)=0$ for any $n,$ where $e_n$ is standard basis sequence. For $f^*=\{f_n\}$ we have $0=f^*(e_n)=f_n$. Thus  $f^*=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc why $f^{*}(e_n) = 0$? Since $c^*$ the same as $l_1$, so $f^*(x) = \sum\limits_{i}y_ix_i$, where $y_i \in l_1$

Comment: The sequence $e_n\in c_0$ hence $f^*(e_n)=0.$ If $f^*(x)=\sum f_kx_k$ then $f^*(e_n)=f_n=0.$ Thus $f^*=0.$

Answer (score 0):

As Reszard Szwarc said in the comments above, if $f^* \in M^{\perp}$ then $f^*(e_n) = 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $e_n$ is standard basis sequence. For $f^* = {f_n}$ we have $0 = f^*(e_n) = f_n$. Thus $f = 0$ and $M^{\perp} = {0}$

Comment: That doesn't look right. The "standard basis" $e_n$ (which I think is $(e_n)_m = $1 if $m = n$ and $0$ otherwise), is not a basis because, for example, the sequence $(1, 1, 1, ...)$ cannot be written as a finite linear combination of those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "other" linear functional (say $p$)  on $c$:  for $x = (x_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ define

$$
p(x) = \lim_{j\to\infty} x_j
$$

Now this element $p \in c^*$ is not zero, since it maps $(1,1,1,\dots)$ to $1$.

In the problem, $M = c_0 \subset c$.  Note that $M$ is the kernel of $p$ by definition.  So $p \in M^\perp$, and thus $M^\perp \ne \{0\}$.